# Return rows with maximum value of a column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
date       | product | price
--------------------------------
17/01/2015 | milk    | 2.54
18/01/2015 | milk    | 2.47
23/01/2015 | milk    | 2.61
21/01/2015 | eggs    | 1.35
04/02/2015 | eggs    | 1.36
27/01/2015 | eggs    | 1.31
```

What I need is a select that returns me the latest price of each product, that is the one with the maximum date. Desired result here would be:

```
23/01/2015 | milk    | 2.61
04/02/2015 | eggs    | 1.36
```

I tried this:

```
select max(date), product, price FROM table GROUP BY product, price
```

but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Could there be multiple entries for the same product on the same date? If so, how would you want to handle that? You're probably looking for [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) or `RANK`.

Comment: No, there'll always be only one price for a product for a single date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery to find each product's last date:

```
select date, product, price
from table t1
where date = (select max(date) from table t2
              where t1.product = t2.product)
```

(After reading  Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment I want to add that if several entries exist with same max date for a product, they will all be returned.)

Comment: I used this solution, nice and elegant. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
select max(date), product,price
from table
group by product, price
```

Comment: That'll complain about price not being in group by or an aggregate

Comment: Which dbms? (Some of them are a bit "flexible"...)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, sorry. Column 'table.Price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If by "works" you mean "In MySQL it will return *a* price value" then yes, it "works". But the question is tagged [tag:tsql]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `ROW_NUMBER()` in `MS SQL`.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE([Date] DATE, Product VARCHAR(40), Price DECIMAL(18,2))

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('01/17/2015', 'milk', '2.54'),
('01/18/2015', 'milk', '2.47'),
('01/23/2015', 'milk', '2.61'),
('01/21/2015', 'egg', '1.35'),
('02/04/2015', 'egg', '1.36'),
('01/27/2015', 'egg', '1.31')

SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY [Date] DESC) RN, Product, Price
     FROM @TABLE
)  Temp
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
   SELECT tb.*
FROM table tb
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  MAX(date), product AS MaxDateTime
    FROM table
    GROUP BY product) groupedtb 
ON tb.product = groupedtb.product 
AND tb.date = groupedtb.MaxDateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you got a reply already, but this also works :)

```
            DECLARE @TableProducts TABLE (
            [date] DATE,
            Product VARCHAR(100),
            Price NUMERIC(9,2)
            );

            INSERT INTO @TableProducts
            VALUES 
            ('17/01/2015', 'milk', 2.54),
            ('18/01/2015', 'milk', 2.47),
            ('23/01/2015', 'milk', 2.61),
            ('21/01/2015', 'eggs', 1.35),
            ('04/02/2015', 'eggs', 1.36),
            ('27/01/2015', 'eggs', 1.31);


            SELECT B.Product, B.Price, A.MostRecentDate
            FROM (
                    SELECT Product, MAX([date]) AS MostRecentDate
                    FROM @TableProducts
                    GROUP BY Product
            ) AS A
            INNER JOIN @TableProducts AS B  ON A.Product = B.Product
                                            AND A.MostRecentDate = B.[date];
```